# Javafx webengine protocols

Tags: java, url-scheme, javafx-webengine

I've created a browser using Javafx, which works fine to go to websites but I'd like to be able to do external protocols (ie: chrome:// or, if you are familiar with nexus mod manager, it launches it via the web using nxm://). I am essentially doing the same thing as nxm on my website, but I want to be able to use the client I have created. Simply typing something like nxm:// yields an about:blank page. Is this possible with jfx?

Edit: I was thinking I could check for a prefix at navigation other than http and https and launch it completely outside the browser?

Comment: Upfront I would have to say no. But If you provided some code to demonstrate how your browser is working, I might change my mind.

Comment: Pretty much this: docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm